# Make calls which does not dampen out musical instruments

Tags: android, music, video-conferencing

I have tried making a regular phone call and using the duo app on android but both of them seems to dampen out non-vocal frequency ranges which makes it really hard to hear my father play the violin or guitar and me to play along. It is like it works for one second but then some kind of misplaced adaptive noise cancelling sets in and ruins the phone call.

Is there any android app you can use for real time calls which does *not* equalize away the instruments? I just want to play along with my dad, it should not be this hard...

Comment: Hi. Have you tried switching off the "Noise reduction" setting under "Call Settings" for Android?

Comment: Unfortunately my settings are in swedish so I don't know how they translated that. I don't find "brusreduktion" which would be the obvious translation.

Comment: There is a setting called "Hörapparater" (hearing aids) which I have turned off, could it be that one?

Comment: On my old Android it is under "Ringtone and sound settings" via "Call Settings". I can't guarantee it will solve your problem but it is good to try it first as it says "Suppresses background noise from your side during calls". You'll need to untick it.

Comment: I do not seem to have that setting. Perhaps it was removed in SG S20.

Comment: Also ask question on https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try different apps that support audio/video calls. I remember having read that Teams app has a relative wide frequency range. But I can't find again the source where I have read that. There are also aps for "online jamming", those apps should be optimized for low latency and wide frequency ranges.

Comment: Asked on https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242544/362785

Answer (score 2):

When non-speech audio gets "muffled", most likely the cause is not client-side filtering but compresssion codec in use that is optimized for speech.

I recommend to use an app that supports explicitly controlling the codec used.

Concretely I suggest to install [BareSIP+](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.tutpro.baresip.plus/), create a SIP account somewhere that promises to support the codec **AMR-WB**, and when configure the account profile to only enable the AMR-WB codec.

Both ends of the conversation must use SIP and both clients need to *support* AMR-WB, but it should be enough that one of the clients is configured to only support that one codec - then the other client should detect that and use the same automatically.